# App Not Set Up: This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it

Tags: facebook, oauth

I have created facebook app. When I am accessing it I am getting below message.

[image: Facebook app error]

In my Apps setting valid email id is already added and I have setup app to public.

[image: App status]

Also Client OAuth Login, Web OAuth Login and Embedded Browser OAuth Login are set to "Yes".

Could you please let me know whats wrong I am doing?

Comment: Did you end up fixing it? Same issue for me

Answer (score -1):

Here is what worked for me:

1) Go to https://developers.facebook.com

2) From the top nav bar select: Apps >> Your App Name >> Status & Review

3) At the top of the Status & Review page you should see "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" with a toggle (no/yes) switch.

4) Click the toggle switch so it displays "Yes".

Also check the web url you provided.

Comment: I'm surprised by how many answers across this site state this even after the op has clearly stated that the app is public already.  It is even shown in the screenshot.  These issues can still come up for an already public app and this is what I and the question are seeking to resolve.